# Node try to find package removed long time ago in :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets stage only

Tags: node.js, react-native, gradle, npm, yarnpkg

I'm working on an app build with react-native.

I installed a package "haul" and 
remove it after I read it's doc more decide not to use it.

then I encounter a problem

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'PATH/node_modules/haul/bin/cli.js'
```

I did the sequence 
`rm -rf node_modules
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*
rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*
npm start -- --reset-cache`

and the problem is gone.

today I try to build a release package, and the problem is back.

only this time it happens in :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets stage only.

I tried a lot of things: remove yarn cache, switch to npm to manage node_modules, switch node version..

this time it won't fix.

I can't even find the string "haul" in my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
project.ext.react = [
  cliPath: "node_modules/haul/bin/cli.js"
]
```

is still in `build.gradle`,
don't know why text find didn't spot it.

anyway, it's fixed now.